# Variable based on previous events

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to know if there are previous events or diagnoses for each period of exposition/non-exposition (exp = 1/0).

I have a database like:

```
id = c( rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5))
exp = c( rep(c(0, 1), 5), c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
diag = c( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
DO = c( c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1))

DT = data.table(id, exp, diag)

DT

    id exp diag
 1:  1   0    1
 2:  1   1    0
 3:  1   0    0
 4:  1   1    0
 5:  1   0    1
 6:  2   1    0
 7:  2   0    0
 8:  2   1    1
 9:  2   0    0
10:  2   1    0
11:  3   0    1
12:  3   1    0
13:  3   0    1
14:  3   1    1
15:  3   0    0
```

I tried with cumsum and fcase:

```
DT [ , previous_diag := cumsum ( diag ), by = .(id)]

DT [ , previous_diag := fcase ( previous_diag > 0 , 1 ,
                                previous_diag == 0 , 0 ) ]
```

But i'm not able to obtain the desired outcome:

```
    id exp diag DO
 1:  1   0    1  0
 2:  1   1    0  1
 3:  1   0    0  1
 4:  1   1    0  1
 5:  1   0    1  1
 6:  2   1    0  0
 7:  2   0    0  0
 8:  2   1    1  0
 9:  2   0    0  1
10:  2   1    0  1
11:  3   0    1  0
12:  3   1    0  1
13:  3   0    1  1
14:  3   1    1  1
15:  3   0    0  1
```

Any ideas?

If it's possible I only want DO to have values when `exp == 1`. Is there any way apart from the obvious one once DO is obtained? I can only think with filter (`exp == 0`) and assign NA's to the DO variable (`DO := NA`).

Thank you all!

Comment: `shift` the values and use `cummax`: `DT[ , DO2 := cummax(shift(diag, fill = 0)), by = id]`

Comment: That's it! After that for the second part: { DT [ exp == 0, DO2 := NA ] }